# Nginx rule for single URL with .php

Tags: nginx, web-hosting

In Nginx I simply need a rule so any body goes to www.example.com/index.php/admin/ should automatically redirected to www.example.com/admin/

I tried different settings but all of them are for redirecting any URL containing .php in middle while I just need it only for particular admin URL

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a redirection for a single specific URL, you can use location with the '=' modifier, as stated in the [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

```
location = '/index.php/admin/' {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/admin/;
}
```

Comment: That is correct, but it is just working for www.example.com/index.php/admin/ exclusively... while for anything like www.example.com/index.php/admin/page1/page2/ it does not work!

Comment: Well, you told in your question that you need it for a single URL, which the answer told how to do.. The URL in your comment is another URL...